# Socket.io & Redis - Proper architecture for an io game?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, redis, socket.io

I'm using a basic **NodeJS** scaling w/ **Redis** architecture, but I'm having trouble configuring this to suit a real-time multiplayer game.

My multiplayer game should have separate lobbies - so when the load balancer places a user in a separate server, there is no way players in the same lobby can communicate, unless I use **Redis**. The problem is, I can't send every single action back and forth between the servers, as that would overload **Redis**, as well as ruin the scalability of the server instances, since now I have to store every user in every NodeJS instance (to check for collisions, ect), which defeats the purpose of scaling. Unless I'm doing something wrong?

**Basic NodeJS/Redis Architecture** (Inefficient for an io game with lobbies?)

[image]

I've also added a separate running **Manager** which configures (creates/removes lobbies) the lobbies, and sends the information to the Worker instances via Redis, so the users so they can view available lobbies

I've thought about having each NodeJS instance to be a separate lobby, but the load balancer doesn't work that way. Also, there is no automatic scaling.

**My current architecture, showcasing players (users)**
[image]

`Red` is for users

`Light Pink` is for synchronized users via Redis from the other servers into itself (otherwise, players from other instances would not be visible to one another. Also, wouldn't be able to perform simple updates, such as collision detection)

Each player is in it's own chosen `lobby`, and is an object which possess `X`, `Y`, `angle`, and several other parameters

Even though users would join `Worker 2` or `Worker 'n'`, I still need to relay the user profiles to other workers, otherwise users that are not on the same `Worker`, they will not be **visible** to one another. Now in this case, doesn't it completely defeat the purpose of scaling?

**Either I'm doing something very wrong, or I'm sure there has to be a solution to this!**

**EDIT**

This is what I have come up with myself so far, albeit not sure if it's plausible

[image]

*I'm getting virtually no help, some comments would be greatly appreciated*

Comment: Why do you need to sync all users in each worker? IIUC,  you just need another middleware that will assign users to a specific worker based on their lobby.

Comment: @sonus21 to check for collision between players as well as bullets fired. The Managers are the middleware.. so you think my architecture is alright?

Comment: Does this game have some sort of group and people play in a group and each group compete against each other? If that's the case then your design seems fine but you can further isolate using game id.

Comment: @sonus21 yes that's exactly it. Albeit I finally got it working. My issue was I didn't realize if I ran everything under 1 instance, the Load Balancer doesn't open any additional ports. So I ran the Workers under a separate Instance with no Load Balancers. Also, I'm just going to run each lobby in a separate instance. I don't like that I have to manually add/remove Workers/Lobbies, but can't have everything x) it's good enough

Thank you for verifying my architecture is solid. Put in an answer, I'll give you the bounty since you're really the only one who tried to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting comment as the answer

As per the comment, the game is played among teams and each team has some members but each member in the game must know about other members(not only their team members),  given each member has to know about all other members in the game, it's good to go with this design.

Though the segregation should be done at a game level, each game should have its own set of Lobbies and each lobby contains all the players.

We don't have to run workers for each Lobby instead one worker can be used for one game and that'll update all the Lobby data.

Also, Loadbalancer should not be used to distribute players among workers instead a middleware should be used in the application like GamePlayerManager/LobbyPlayerManager to add/remove a player to/from a specific lobby.